# Looking for a classic sci-fi short story about a boy who discovers pods growing in a field

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

For years, I've been looking for a short story about a boy who discovers alien pods in a field that are growing replacement people. If I remember right, he sees the pod creature eat his mother and then become her, and no one believes him. The story ends with him going in to see his dad, one of the few real people left until that point, and seeing something (an empty pod maybe) that lets him know his dad has been taken and he's next. I'm thinking that the title was something like Father Figure, but I may be remembering wrong.

The story was part of several collections of classic science fiction stories that we had on our bookcase when I was growing up, so I'm guessing that the story could be from the 70's or any time earlier.

Comment: Are you certain it's a short story? Your description fits the movie "Invasion of the Body Snatchers" very well.

Comment: I'm sure, although the movie could have been taken from the story maybe (I don't enjoy horror movies, so pretty sure I've never seen that one). I was probably 9 or 10 the first time I read the story, and I'm not sure I ever looked at my parents the same way again. :)

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you!!! I've been looking for this story for years, and with your description, started searching for it by looking for the story that Invasion of the Body Snatchers was based on, which lead to other stories about the same subject. The story I've been looking for is "The Father Thing" by Philip K. Dick. Thank you again! :)

Comment: Apparently I can't accept my own answer for another 2 days. I'll do that as soon as I'm able to. :)

Comment: Seems like a good-read.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The story is "[The Father Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Father-thing)" by Philip K. Dick. Thank you so much, Michael Stern for your suggestion that lead to finding the story. :)